# Asymptotic directions for a surface which is only locally a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the map 
$$f(u,v) = (u - \frac{u^3}{3} + uv^2, v - \frac{v^3}{3} + u^2v, u^2 - v^2)$$

Although $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not a manifold, I know that for any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I can choose $r$ such that $M_x=f(B(x,r))$ is a manifold (this is known: I do not want to prove this).

$f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is plotted below:

[image]
Now, I want to determine the asymptotic lines at $p=f(x)$ in $M_x$, for any $x$.

My plan was the following:

1 - Determine the Gauss map $N(p)$.
2 - Determine the (matrix of the) Weingarten map $-dN(p)$.
3 - Determine the Gauss curvature.
4 - Conclude what type of point $p$ is (elliptic, hyperbolic,... ). This will tell us what are the asymptotic directions (if any).

I rapidly noticed that this would be troublesome. The Gauss map is complicated:

$$
       N(p) = \frac{ f_u\times f_v }{\parallel f_u\times f_v \parallel} 
$$
and 
$$
f_u=\left(-u^{2} + v^{2} + 1,\,2 \, u
v,\,2 \, u\right) ,\ fv=\left(2 \, u v,\,u^{2} - v^{2} +
1,\,-2 \, v\right)
$$
So
$$               
 N(p)=\left(-\frac{2 \, {\left(2 \, u v^{2}
+ {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} u\right)}}{\sqrt{{\left| -4 \, u^{2}
v^{2} - {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} -
1\right)} \right|}^{2} + {\left| 4 \, u^{2} v - 2 \, {\left(u^{2} -
v^{2} - 1\right)} v \right|}^{2} + {\left| -4 \, u v^{2} - 2 \,
{\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} u \right|}^{2}}},\,\frac{2 \, {\left(2
\, u^{2} v - {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} - 1\right)} v\right)}}{\sqrt{{\left|
-4 \, u^{2} v^{2} - {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} {\left(u^{2} -
v^{2} - 1\right)} \right|}^{2} + {\left| 4 \, u^{2} v - 2 \,
{\left(u^{2} - v^{2} - 1\right)} v \right|}^{2} + {\left| -4 \, u v^{2}
- 2 \, {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} u \right|}^{2}}},\,-\frac{4 \,
u^{2} v^{2} + {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} -
1\right)}}{\sqrt{{\left| -4 \, u^{2} v^{2} - {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} +
1\right)} {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} - 1\right)} \right|}^{2} + {\left| 4 \,
u^{2} v - 2 \, {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} - 1\right)} v \right|}^{2} + {\left|
-4 \, u v^{2} - 2 \, {\left(u^{2} - v^{2} + 1\right)} u
\right|}^{2}}}\right)
$$

(I used SageMath to compute this)

I would like to write this in terms of the tangent vectors (of the natural basis) $f_u$ and $f_v$ in order to write down the matrix of the Weingarten map, but I do not see how.
Certainly I am overcomplicating things, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enneper's surface is quite famous. You really do not want to compute the matrix of $dN(p)$. Rather, you should just calculate the first and second fundamental forms. They come out rather simple and easy to work with. Here's the answer:
$$
I = \begin{bmatrix} (1+u^2+v^2)^2 & 0 \\ 0 & (1+u^2+v^2)^2\end{bmatrix} \qquad\text{and}$$
$$II = \begin{bmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
If you do not already know this, work out why the matrix of $-dN(p)$ with respect to the basis $\{f_u,f_v\}$ is precisely the matrix product $I^{-1}II$.

By the way, computer algebra systems are notoriously bad at simplifying algebraic expressions. Things aren't as bad as you think with $N(p)$. In particular, you should note that
\begin{gather*}
f_u\times f_v = (1+u^2+v^2)\big({-}2u, 2v, 1-u^2-v^2\big) \quad\text{and} \\(-2u)^2+(2v)^2+(1-u^2-v^2)^2 = (1+u^2+v^2)^2.
\end{gather*}
In particular, get in the habit of factoring out as much as you can *before* you divide by the length of the vector!

Comment: Ok: I managed to prove the relation between the Weingarten map and the fundamental forms. I have a problem, though. I have seen the second fundamental form defined as $B(v,w)=\langle -dN(v),w \rangle$, so I need to know the weingarten map in the first place, in order to determine the second fundamental form...

Comment: That's the definition, but that is *not* how one calculates it. Because $\langle f_u,N\rangle = 0$, for example, differentiating with respect to $u$ gives $\langle f_{uu}, N\rangle + \langle f_u, dN(f_u)\rangle = 0$, so $B(f_u,f_u) = \langle f_{uu}, N\rangle$. Continue ... (See p. 46 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) if you need to.)

Comment: I see... So I only have to compute $N$, not $dN$. Great!

Comment: Yup. I would hope that your course/text discussed this crucial point.

Comment: It does not, unfortunately...

Comment: Hmm, you might want to download my (free) text.

Comment: I did! I will only have time to study it in a while, though

Comment: One more thing: I found that the  asymptotic directions correspond to the vectors of the type $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$. If I now want to find a point and an asymptotic curve going through it (I believe I can choose the origin as the point and choose the asymptotic direction $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$), how can I go about it? I thought on trying to solve 
$$
\begin{cases}\gamma(0)=0
\\ \gamma'(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: But this does not seem easily solvable (after substituting the expressions for the derivatives)

Comment: You're making this too hard. The integral curves are just $v=\pm u +c$ for various constants $c$.

Comment: Hmm I do not know what you mean by $v=\pm u+c$ and how it relates with what I wrote..

Comment: I'm not solving for parametrized curves. I'm by inspection giving you curves with the appropriate tangent vectors $(1,\pm 1)$ everywhere in the $uv$-plane.

Comment: I see. But I want curves on the manifold such that its tangent vector is of that type (and, I forgot to say, I would like the curve to have non-zero curvature). But it seems that you are giving me curves (two straight lines for each constant $c$) in the $uv$-plane.

Comment: The $uv$-plane parametrizes the manifold, remember? That's the whole point of working in (local) coordinates.

Comment: I get it now!
I have to thank you. I learned a lot from this.

Comment: You're quite welcome!